# Anonymous arrow functions cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this code in my `pages/index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const TVChartContainer = dynamic(
    () =>
        import('../components/TVChartContainer').then(mod => mod.TVChartContainer),
    { ssr: false },
);

export default () => <TVChartContainer />;
```

And this gives me an error.

> Anonymous arrow functions cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local
> component state. Please add a name to your function, for example:
>
> Before export default () => ;
>
> After const Named = () => ; export default Named;
>
> A codemod is available to fix the most common cases:
> https://nextjs.link/codemod-ndc

And then I tried to export the component this way.

```
export default  TVChartContainer;
```

This also seems not fixing the issue.
How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, you need to add a name to the function component you're exporting.

```js
const IndexPage = () => <TVChartContainer />

export default IndexPage;
```